# How can I allow the user to draw with a mouse but keep the line restricted to a grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like the player to be able to draw on a grid at runtime. I'm using C# and so far the most stable solution I've found is a fairly simple one

```
vectorLine.points3.Add(WorldGridUtilities.getWorldTile(currentNode).gridCoordinates);
```

Vectorline is a method that vectrosity uses to draw lines.

WorldGridUtilities is a class I have made. In the above example is returns a Vector3 coordinate in world space of the nearest node on my grid.

However, when the user moves the mouse quickly it can skip over grid points.

This image explains the problem.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `interpolate` the missing points using a very simple algorithm:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Interpolate(Tuple<int, int> from, Tuple<int, int> to)
{
    var intermediatePoints = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    int lastX = from.Item1;
    int lastY = from.Item2;
    while (Math.Abs(lastX - to.Item1) > 1)
    {
        lastX = lastX - Math.Sign(lastX - to.Item1);
        intermediatePoints.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(lastX, lastY));
    }
    while (Math.Abs(lastY - to.Item2) > 1)
    {
        lastY = lastY - Math.Sign(lastY - to.Item2);
        intermediatePoints.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(lastX, lastY));
    }
    return intermediatePoints;
}
```

If you repeatedly get very large steps, you could interleave X and Y steps to get a `Manhattan` route.

**Update**: see a [complete example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a05506ce72682f969e97) (console application) using Manhattan steps.

Comment: Hi CaringDev, thanks very much for your answer. I understood the lines within the method but wasn't sure what the first line was  `public static IEnumerable`, I found it quite hard to read as I'm at a fairly self-taught intermediate level. I'm familiar with coroutines and such but not used to what you wrote, would you mind explaining a little or pointing me towards some documentation? Thanks again! I Appreciate your response.

Comment: Hi there. I think you are confusing IEnumerable with IEnumerator. The coroutine returns an IEnumerator. @CharingDev 's function returns an IEnumerable which is a base class for collection types like List, Dictionary, etc. For example you can declare a variable of type List<Tuple<int, int>>, then assign to it whatever this function returns. [Read about IEnumerable here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much Nika, that was well explained

Comment: @Jim I created a commented gist (see updated answer). For the documentation, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: Thats probably the most comprehensive answer I have ever had, thanks very much for taking the time to help.

Comment: Thanks. I also liked your question, especially the image for clarification.